# VBA to Copy Contents from Embedded Word document and retain formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using `Excel 2010` with an embedded Word Document.  The Word document is basically a communication template with some formatting (bold / underline / hyperlinks).

**Process:**  User opens Excel Document, provides inputs to Excel, and completes template.  There is no interaction between the inputs in Excel and the contents of the template.

I'm trying to build out this process such that once they edit the `embedded Word Document` the user hits a `button`. The `VBA` code would then take the contents of the `embedded Word document` and paste (formatting and all) it as the body of the email.  The file would attach itself to that email, and off it would go for approval.

I've been able to locate code to get me part of the way there, and to give props where props are due, I located the code [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/how-do-i-copy-from-an-embedded-word-object-with-a/ee2b3cce-3171-4b58-9b08-75606ac6e5be) (see below for the code)

But this doesn't retain the Word Document's Formatting.  Any recommendations?  Maybe if I could extract the Word contents as HTML that would work.  But not sure how to do that.  All help appreciated.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim Oo As OLEObject
  Dim wDoc As Object 'Word.Document

  'Search for the embedded Word document
  For Each Oo In Sheet8.OLEObjects
    If InStr(1, Oo.progID, "Word.Document", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'Open the embedded document
        Oo.Verb xlVerbPrimary
        'Get the document inside
        Set wDoc = Oo.Object

        'Copy the contents to cell A1
        wDoc.Content.Copy
        With Sheet8.Range("M1")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With


        'Select any cell to close the document
        Sheet8.Range("M1").Select
        'Done
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  Set wDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

After reviewing comintern's code, I was getting an error I couldn't solve for.  I went back to the boards and located some additional code.  Merging the two seems to have fixed it.

```
Sub HTMLExport()
Dim objOnSheet As oleObject
Dim strFileName As String
Dim sh As Shape
Dim objWord As Object ''Word.Document
Dim objOLE As oleObject

Sheet8.Activate
Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes("RA_Template")
sh.OLEFormat.Activate
Set objOLE = sh.OLEFormat.Object
Set objWord = objOLE.Object

ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Activate

''Easy enough
strFileName = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\temp.html"
objWord.SaveAs2 Filename:=strFileName, FileFormat:=10  '10=wdFormatFilteredHTML


'Copy the file contents into cell M1...
Dim handle As Integer
    handle = FreeFile
    Open strFileName For Input As handle
    Sheet8.Range("M1").Value = Input$(LOF(handle), handle)
    Close handle

'Delete the Temp File (strFileName)
Kill strFileName

'Select any cell to close the document
Sheet8.Range("M1").Select
```

End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If getting it into HTML will work (Word makes pretty ugly HTML...), you can just save it to a temp file and then pick it back up:

```
Sub HTMLExport()
    Dim Oo As OLEObject

    'Search for the embedded Word document
    For Each Oo In Sheet8.OLEObjects
        If InStr(1, Oo.progID, "Word.Document", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Dim temp As String
            'GetSpecialFolder(2) gives the user's temp folder.
            temp = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\temp.html"
            '10 = wdFormatFilteredHTML
            Oo.Object.SaveAs2 temp, 10

            'Copy the file contents into cell M1...
            Dim handle As Integer
            handle = FreeFile
            Open temp For Input As handle
            Sheet8.Range("M1").Value = Input$(LOF(handle), handle)
            Close handle
            '...and delete the temp file.
            Kill temp

            'Select any cell to close the document
            Sheet8.Range("M1").Select
            'Done
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that if you're using this method, you can't open the embedded Word document after you get the OLEObject or Word won't allow you to save it.

Comment: Thank you.  I think this might work, but I'm getting the "1004 "unable to get the object property of the oleobject class"" error.  I can't seem to locate a fix for this.  Any work-arounds?

Comment: That's odd.  Is it on this statement: `Oo.Object.SaveAs2 temp, 10`?

Comment: @Lee_Str - Do you have ActiveX controls enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is on the  `Oo.Object.SaveAs2 temp, 10` line.  And yes, my ActiveX controls are enabled.  I'm able to use the Button Control just fine.

Comment: Continued to research this and couldn't found a fix.  Did some research, and found a similar solution.  Merged two and they now work.  thank you for your help Comintern.  You got me on the right path!

Comment: @Lee_Str - Just for the benefit of others who find this, what was the solution to the 1004 error?